# Lagrange multipliers for minimax optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Does the equally constrained minimax optimization can be solved by using Lagrange multiplier method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have a similar question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2745136/10063