# Linearly constrained saddle-point optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f(x,y)$ be a smooth (twice differentiable) saddle function (convex in $x$ and concave in $y$), where $f \colon X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $X \subset \mathbb R^n$, $Y \subset \mathbb R^m$ are convex compact sets.

I consider a constrained optimization problem of the form:

$$\min_{x \in X} \max_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$$

subject to:

$$A x + B y = c$$

where $A \in \mathbb R^{r\times n}, B \in \mathbb R^{r\times m}, c \in \mathbb R^r$.

Can $\min\max$ be exchanged with $\max\min$?  Is the following equality true or false?

$$\min_{x \in X} \max_{y \in Y} f(x,y) = \max_{y \in Y} f(x,y)\min_{x \in X}$$

If this is false, I would like to see a counterexample to understand why.

Comment: I know that you can use the so-called Minimax Theorem, which says under which conditions you can interchange the min and the max.

Comment: @Tobias The minimax theorem that I know about, only applies in absence of constrains. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem